# Width doesn't respond according to the media query

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, media-queries

I was experimenting with media queries to see the effects.
So I tried using `min-width(480px)` query to change the width of a `div` from `100%` to `520px` *when the window was maximised* but the width of the `div` stays `100%`.

**The code:**

```
#box {
    margin: auto;
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
}
// Media Queries
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    #box {
        width: 200px;
        max-width: 200px;
        background: black;
    }
}
```

So my question is, why does the width of the `#box` stay as `100%` *when the window is maximised*?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Do you have a meta tag specified in your markup? (ie. <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">)

Comment: only screen and (min-width: 480px) means :: when at least 480 pixels are available ..

Comment: @Adrift interestingly enough it works in http://jsfiddle.net/_1907FB/Jm2Lw/1/ but not standalone

Comment: @user1855126 yes I used to but now that I took it out, it still doesn't work

Comment: @MilchePatern Yep, I start the window small and then enlarge it. It should then effect the box shouldn't it?

Comment: Never mind I got it working :)

Answer (score 2):

[jsFiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/D8ANz/3/) is your code with min-width:480px. It applies when the size of available space is bigger than 480px (the black box)

try **max-width**. This context will apply when available screen space is less then 480 pixels. [jsFiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/D8ANz/4/), black box will be applied when available space width is lesser than 480px

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #box {
        width: 200px;
        max-width: 200px;
        background: black;
    }
}
```

So, your #box is by default 100% width except when the available space is greater than 480px. your code is working OK.

Maybe it's the comment : **// Media Queries** witch caused an error ?

Comment: @MMM ?? What do you mean ? Even the OP doesn't express fenerlitk thought, but he want's to know why it is not working. It's caused by the min-width query.

Comment: "So my question is, why does the width of the #box stay as 100% when the window is maximised?" He **wants** to use `min-width`, it's not a mistake...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the media query wrong. As you have it now, it's changes the content **over** 480px. Where I think you want it under 480px.

So it should be:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  //code
}
```

Hence, `(max-width: xxx)` not, `(min-width: xxx)`.

**[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LBffq/)**

Comment: No, you're wrong. He says that is stays "as 100% when the window is maximised", so he wants it to kick in when something is over 480px.

Comment: @MMM Sly edit change 30 minutes later...(correct at the time)

Answer (score 0):

I had commented the code using `//` syntax by accident which isn't supported in CSS, hence the code below that line of comment not working. It now works after I changed it `/**/` syntax.